# Where to install Mercanet Payment Lib on linux

Tags: linux, installation, payment, libraries, installation-path

I have to install a payment solution kit - ATOS Merc@net BnpParisBas - on an amazon linux 64 server for our web application. The kit provides a library that needs to be install on the server.

Is there any recommended location where i have to install the lib?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a debian or ubuntu installation, I would put it into `/usr/local`. The reference what belongs where is the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any reason to put it into a web application directory (under the public web folder). For example in a lib directory.
I'm using Symfony, and there's a vendor folder. Should i put the lib there too? Thanks!

Comment: if it's a PHP library that gets included by your source, add it to the vendor folder and check into revision control. But only put it in one place.